# Hubbard-Stratonovich for 4-component attractive interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, path-integral, many-body, superfluidity

Suppose we are dealing with a hamiltonian similar to a BCS one, but instead of the 2-component interaction we are dealing with something of the form: $-g\psi^\dagger_1\psi^\dagger_2\psi^\dagger_3\psi^\dagger_4\psi_4\psi_3\psi_2\psi_1$, where all the psi's are Grassman variables.

Now let's define the SU(4) spinor $\Psi=(\psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3,\psi_4)^T$, such that the interaction is written as $-\frac{g}{4!}(\Psi^\dagger\Psi)^4$.

My goal would be doing Feynman diagram expansion of the partition function, through path integral, but first I have to do a Hubbard-Stratonovich (HS) transformation. I expect a non zero VEV (gap of superfluid 4-body state), for the fluctuating bosonic field in the path integral after HS.

If I naively take $\Phi=g\psi_1\psi_2\psi_3\psi_4$ as the auxiliary field (similar to BCS case) and then expand as $\Phi=\phi_0+g\varphi$, I don't seem to have a gap in the energy, because I do not get something quadratic but quartic in the fields.

What should be the correct HS transformation then? Or what would be the correct definition for the spinor, if the one which I used is wrong?

**EDIT 1**: We are working in d=4/3 dimensions. It could cause some problems for the integrals but for now I need the right HS transformation.

Comment: Curious if you ever found an answer for this?